# Is there a general formula for number of integral points inside the circle $x^2+y^2=a^2$ for $a \in \mathbb Z^+$

Tags: combinatorics, circles

I could work out a general formula for number of integral (lattice) points lying on or inside the circle $x^2+y^2=a^2$, $a \in\mathbb{Z}^+$

See [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dz4bmLd9IYo&list=PLoetsRqdeRZkQc0DXztib5G8ZzYXipI05)

I tried to work out a general formula for number of integral (lattice) points lying strictly inside the circle $x^2+y^2=a^2$, $a \in\mathbb{Z}^+$. Well, I can remove points lying on the circle when in my formula term inside the greatest integer is an integer, but i was wondering if there is any general formula possible for the same.

Comment: @amWhy Thank you for the edit

Comment: There is a formula by Gauss: $$N(a) = 1 + 4\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\left\lfloor \frac{a^2}{4k+1}\right\rfloor - \left\lfloor \frac{a^2}{4k+3}\right\rfloor\right)$$ See wiki entry of [Gauss circle problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_circle_problem) for more info.

Comment: Notice that the series always reduces to a finite sum.

Comment: @achille that formula includes points on and inside

Comment: I did consider counting Pythagorean triplets and discounting such points but that akin to getting an integer inside greatest integer function

Comment: @Fimpellizieri yeah, after a while $a^2$<4k+1 so all successive terms will be zero in the series

Comment: $\# \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}^2 : x^2 + y^2 < a^2 \} = \lim_{r \to a-} N(r)$.

Comment: @achille say if the value of a=6 then how do we  get this $lim_{r}\rightarrow{5^-} N(r)$

Comment: Since $\lim_{x \to y-} \lfloor x \rfloor = \lceil y \rceil - 1$, $\lim_{r\to a-}N(r)$ is equivalent to replace floors by ceilings in definition of $N(a)$.

Comment: You might be interested in the theory of Erhart polynomials.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a neat formula for it.

This is called the Gauss circle problem. You can find more details here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_circle_problem.

Comment: Notice that the series in the linked article reduces to a finite sum.

Comment: Well, that formula is applicable for $x^2+y^2\le a^2$ and even i am not sure if there is a formula for strictly inside points.