# Number of lattice point inside a circle in general position.

Tags: circles, integer-lattices

There is a lot of literature for [number-of-lattice-points-inside-a-circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3576458/is-there-a-general-formula-for-number-of-integral-points-inside-the-circle-x2) when the circle is centred at the origin, see for example the [Gauss circle problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_circle_problem). But what happens if the requirement for the centre is dropped and instead we consider a circle in general position and want bounds on the minimum and maximum number of lattice points?

In a question on [another site](https://www.quora.com/How-many-grid-points-can-be-inside-or-on-a-circle-of-radius-r-sqrt-23-if-you-throw-that-circle-anywhere-on-the-lattice-grid-Z-times-Z-Same-question-for-r-sqrt-20/answer/Richard-Morris-34), experimental results for $r=\sqrt{23}$ show the maximum is 76, more than the 69 for the circle centred at the origin. The opposite occurs for $r=\sqrt{20}$, and the maximum number of points, 69, occurs for a circle centre the origin, but the minimum number is 58.

Are there any results for this wider problem?

Answer (score 3):

A first, simple estimate can be obtained as follows by simple geometry and subset relation of circles:

Let $C(r,P)$ denote the circle of radius $r$ around point $P$, and let  $\#C$ be the number of lattice points in $C$.

The first observation is that we can take $P$ mod 1 and the number of lattice points does not change because the lattice is $\Bbb Z^2$ and $x-(x\bmod 1)\in\Bbb Z$:

$$\#C(r,P) = \#C(r,P \bmod 1) \tag 1$$

where for a real number $x$ we chose remainders of $x\bmod 1$ in $[-1/2, 1/2]$; and for a point $P=(x,y)$ we set $P \bmod 1 := (x\bmod 1, y\bmod1)$.  Thus
$P\bmod 1\in[-1/2,1/2]^2$. Moreover we have

$$C(r,P) \subseteq C(r+|P|,0) \tag 2$$

and thus

$$\#C(r,P) = \#C(r,P \bmod 1)\leqslant \#C(r + |P \bmod 1|,0)$$

where $|P \bmod 1|\leqslant 1/\sqrt 2$. A bound from below follows from

$$C(r-|P|,0) \subseteq C(r,P) \tag 3$$

where the circle on the left side decays to the empty set for $|P|>r$.  Taking it together:

$$\#C(r-|P \mod 1|,0) ~\leqslant~ \#C(r,P) ~\leqslant~ \#C(r+|P\bmod 1|, 0) \tag 4$$

and the less strict version

$$\#C(r-1/\sqrt2,0) ~\leqslant~ \#C(r,P) ~\leqslant~ \#C(r+1/\sqrt2, 0) \tag 5$$

For example, when you have a circle of radius $r$ around $P=(3.3, 6.6)$, then $|P\bmod 1|= \sqrt{0.3^2+0.4^2}=1/2$, and the number of points is bounded between the number of points of the circles or radius $r\pm1/2$ around the origin.